# Three.JS - Scrolling issues in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

I am not sure if anyone else is having this problem or not with three.js. I have a [simple demo](http://cmg0030.zxq.net/acclDemo2) of a cube that will spin with a varying rotational velocity (arrow keys, mouse, or touch input). Everything seems to work fantastic in the Chrome browser. At work I hopped on the iMac, the textures seem to be splicing and not mapped to my geometry correctly in Safari.

I moved over to the Firefox browser on the mac and everything works, and the frame rate is decent. It just seems that for some reason when the cube gets rotated at certain angles the renderer jumps and the onscreen hud moves up and you can't see the title at the top and the stats widget moves up from the bottom of the screen. It also seems that my cube's y position jumps up at the same time. I seem to have the same problem in android on some of the mobile browsers. I was wondering if anyone has had similar issues in Firefox (on Mac?) or in mobile browsers with the rendering suddenly jumping, moving the onscreen hud, etc

EDIT: I have figured out the problem. I still do not have an ideal solution. I created a copy of my demo and tried commenting out my keyboard handling code and to my surprise the issue still existed. Apparently firefox is scrolling the window slightly up and down and the keyboard handler included in the [THREEx library](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex) does not disable the default behavior of the up and down arrow keys in Firefox. In chrome there is no room to scroll my window and I simply make my renderer the size of the window. I do not see why firefox is scrolling.

Comment: On my android device (LG Optimus T running a ported Cyanogenmod 7) the "y jump" you're talking about isn't happening but the texture splicing is. Just adding my device's two cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason in Firefox (not Chrome) there is room to scroll even though the renderer is set to the window size, so Firefox was scrolling when using the arrow keys. To fix this, I edited two functions in [THREEx.KeyboardState.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex/blob/master/THREEx.KeyboardState.js) adding a preventDefault() to prevent the arrow keys from scrolling.

Here are the needed edits:

```
this._onKeyDown = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    self._onKeyChange(event, true); 
};
this._onKeyUp   = function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    self._onKeyChange(event, false);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I experiment the same problems on Firefox in Mac on your example.

The jumps on the rendering are due the garbage collector (poorly implemented on Firefox). You are allocating memory on each "animate" function.

Instead of creating new Vector3/Matrix4 for your rotation, use global variables, so you just create those objects once.

Besides, instead of using KeyboardState, and executing those 'State' functions on each animate call, you should use a KeyboardListener, which will execute your code just when something changes (and not all the time).

You should take a look to this example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html

Comment: Ok, I tried to delete the first lines of my rotation functions as you suggest (I pulled these functions from a discussion on github and edited them to suit my needs). I made rotationMatrix a global variable initialized at the beginning of my program it broke the demo and you can't rotate the cube. Other than that no errors given. Not sure of the mechanics of the functions so I don't know why. Gonna try and find some examples with matrix rotations and see how its done there.

Comment: Actually, it seems that if you run it in firefox (on Windows at least, you can simply hit the up and down keys and it will make the frame jump. After some further experimenting I have found that it appears to only be happening with they arrow key inputs. The keyboard handler object is just a wrapper around the event listener I believe with some other helping code, but it may have an error that is causing this in firefox. Will try to change my code to use standard key events to see if that helps. Thanks for the input.